# What is the problem with my approach for calculating an explicit formula for S(n,4) (stirling numbers of the second kind)?

Tags: combinatorics

I know and understand the general formula for S(n,4) so I know this approach is not correct. But why can't we count this in the following way instead. First we choose 4 elements from the n to fill each partition (so we guarantee no empty partitions). This can be done in n choose 4 ways. Then for the remaining (n-4) elements we have 4 options as to where to place them. We then divide by 4! as we don't care about the order of the partitions themselves (they all look/are labeled the same). So we end up with:

${n \choose 4} \frac{4^{n-4}}{4!}$

This answer is incorrect and does not line up with the general formula for S(n,k), but I'm wondering why not? Where is the counting issue?

Comment: Those $4$ elements you chose at the beginning have been distinguished. In a real partition you can't tell which elements were chosen "first." So you've overcounted there. Your division by $4!$ is also confusing because you already divided by $4!$ with the binomial coefficient; note that when $n = 4$ the result here is not an integer.

Comment: Ah, I see. This makes a lot of sense now, thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Oh, sorry, I somehow missed that Qiaochu Yuan already pointed out the extra division by $4!$. Anyway, I've spelled it out below.

In addition to Qiaochu Yuan's comment, your formula does't even yield integers. If you removed the $4!$, then you would be counting the number of partitions into $4$ **pointed** subsets, meaning subsets with a specified distinguished element (you can think of it as the "leader" of the set).

To illustrate, say $n=7$. First, choose the $4$ leaders, say $\{1,2,4,5\}$. This can be done in $\binom n4$ ways. Then, for each of the remaining elements, we choose which leader they should join, say $3$ joins $1$, and $6$ and $7$ join $4$, meaning we get the partition $\{1^*,3\},\{2^*\},\{4^*,6,7\},\{5^*\}$. I've marked the leaders with a star. The last step can be done in $4^{n-4}$ ways. We don't divide by $4!$ again, because the groups are distinguishable by their leader.

Comment: Thank you so much! This really cleared things up for me.